# Issues with multiple selection in nautilus grid view in ubuntu 21.04

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 21.04

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04/GNOME with Nautilus file browser side by side with Windows 10 on decent hardware.

Multiple selection in **Nautilus grid view** stopped working properly for me.

1. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse</kbd> clicks only selects the last item clicked, but works normally in list view.
2. Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse</kbd> clicks only highlights the last item clicked, but works normally in list view and on desktop.
3. Holding down left mouse click and dragging the mouse does not show a selection box nor selects multiple items in both grid and list views, but works on the desktop.
4. Additionally, selecting an item in nautilus then holding down left mouse click and **dragging** the mouse to **drop** it in another folder in Nautilus or another app like VLC does not work, but works normally from list view and on desktop.

I think this was caused by something I did, but I don't know what it is.

Is there any way to restore these functions to normal?